# How to remove quotes from ARRAY_AGG in mysql using knex

Tags: mysql, knex.js, mysql-json

I am using knex and trying to query for an array of objects using `JSON_ARRAYAGG` and `JSON_OBJECT`. Unfortunately, the whole array that is being returned from `JSON_ARRAYAGG` is wrapped in single quotes, and I can't seem to get rid of them.

My query looks very similar to this:

```
let data = await knex('table1')
    .join('table2')
    .where({ 'table1.id': id })
    .select(
      'a',
      'b',
      knex.raw(
        'JSON_ARRAYAGG(json_object("c", c, "d", d)) ->> $.itemArr AS itemArr',
      ),
    )
    .groupBy('id');
```

I've tried doing the following:

1. the `->>` operator,
2. the `->` + `JSON_UNQUOTE`
3. `knex.raw('CAST(JSON_ARRAYAGG(json_object('c', c, 'd', d)) AS JSON ) AS itemArr')`
4. `knex.raw('CAST(JSON_ARRAYAGG(json_object('c', c, 'd', d)) AS itemArr) AS JSON ')`
5. `knex.raw('JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT(JSON_ARRAYAGG(json_object('c', c, 'd', d))), $.specialties) AS JSON ')`

I'm quite new to mySQL so I don't know if this is right, but according to other posts I've found on SO, these are the proposed solutions. Any help would be appreciated

Note: the -> and ->> operators gave me a parsing error.

Edit: I also get an unknown column field error when using $.itemArr as a path.

Comment: Show us some sample data and table, your current query output and your expected output.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to figure out how to do it. I'm not sure if it's the most efficient way of doing it, but I just ended doing what the following post did: https://github.com/knex/knex/issues/2416.

Essentially, i ended up adding the following when connecting to knex:

```
typeCast: function (field, next) {
      if (field.type === 'JSON') {
        return (JSON.parse(field.string()))
      }
      return next()
    }
```

From what I understand, when the query result is a JSON type, it automatically parses it for me.